# networkx layout

Tags: layout, matplotlib, networkx

I currently have a list of triplets of the form (node1, node2, weight_of_edge). Is there some way for me to plot so that nodes that have an edge between them stay close together in the layout?

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality in matplotlib. There are very powerful network visualization tools that do provide this. Have a look at [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.com) library that provides a lot of tools for the creation and manipulation of networks.

A basic example based on a list of triplets:

```
list_of_triplets = [("n1", "n2", 4),
                    ("n3", "n4", 1),
                    ("n5", "n6", 2),
                    ("n7", "n8", 4),
                    ("n1", "n7", 4),
                    ("n2", "n8", 4),
                    ("n8", "n9", 6),
                    ("n4", "n9", 12),
                    ("n4", "n6", 1),
                    ("n2", "n7", 4),
                    ("n1", "n8", 4)]

# The line below in the code change the list in a format that take
# a weight argument in a dictionary, to be computed by NetworkX

formatted_list = [(node[0], node[1], {"weight":node[2]}) for node in list_of_triplets]
```

To draw the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(formatted_list)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

[image: nodes]